# Pytrends error: failed on_status, TrendReq.trending_searches() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python

I would like to get the latest Google Trends with Pytrends. I have installed a completely new system with Python 3.10.1 and Pytrends. The code is quite simple:

```
#pip install pytrends

from pytrends.request import TrendReq

pytrends = TrendReq.trending_searches(pn='US')
print(pytrends.head(20))
```

However, I still get this error message:

```
TypeError: TrendReq.trending_searches() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I can't find any help with googeling. Do any of you have an idea what the problem is here?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for me. With the examples on the github page of Pytrends:

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq

pytrend = TrendReq()

trending_searches_df = pytrend.trending_searches(pn = "united_states")
print(trending_searches_df.head())
```

I can't explain why so many tutorials on the Internet have the wrong code. But with this it works without problems.